# WARN Cannot create filesystem for url jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/: null java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: null

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I tried to dockerize my spring boot application and achived this error

> WARN Cannot create filesystem for url
> jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/: null
> java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: null.

What am I doing wrong? Without docker application work fine.

Problem disappeared after I delete liquibase dependency from pom.xml What can be wrong with liquibase?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  activemq:
    image: rmohr/activemq:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: activemq
    environment:
      - ACTIVEMQ_USERNAME=admin
      - ACTIVEMQ_PASSWORD=admin
    restart: unless-stopped
  simplewebapp:
    image: simplewebapp
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: simplewebapp
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - activemq
    links:
      - activemq
```

Running with `docker build -t simplewebapp .` and then `docker-compose up` and I am recieving this in console:

```
C:\Users\Vasiliev\Desktop\projects\simplewebapp>docker build -t simplewebapp .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  56.21MB
Step 1/7 : FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
 ---> a3562aa0b991
Step 2/7 : MAINTAINER Vasiliev A
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 18f600863d67
Step 3/7 : VOLUME /tmp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 23a191d44d82
Step 4/7 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 853804494bea
Step 5/7 : ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fd23891bd332
Step 6/7 : COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 81c37844ac5b
Step 7/7 : ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 090cc2dd4775
Successfully built 090cc2dd4775
Successfully tagged simplewebapp:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

and this after `docker-compose up`

```
C:\Users\Vasiliev\Desktop\projects\simplewebapp>docker-compose up
Starting activemq ... done
Recreating simplewebapp ... done
Attaching to activemq, simplewebapp
activemq        | INFO: Loading '/opt/activemq/bin/env'
activemq        | INFO: Using java '/docker-java-home/jre/bin/java'
activemq        | bin/activemq: 1: bin/activemq: ps: not found
activemq        | INFO: Starting in foreground, this is just for debugging purposes (stop process by pressing CTRL+C)
activemq        | INFO: Creating pidfile /opt/activemq/data/activemq.pid
activemq        | Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_181 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
activemq        |   Heap sizes: current=62976k  free=58715k  max=932352k
activemq        |     JVM args: -Xms64M -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/activemq/conf/login.config -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/activemq/tmp -Dactivemq
.classpath=/opt/activemq/conf:/opt/activemq/../lib/: -Dactivemq.home=/opt/activemq -Dactivemq.base=/opt/activemq -Dactivemq.conf=/opt/activemq/conf -Dactivemq.data=/opt/activemq/data
activemq        | Extensions classpath:
activemq        |   [/opt/activemq/lib,/opt/activemq/lib/camel,/opt/activemq/lib/optional,/opt/activemq/lib/web,/opt/activemq/lib/extra]
activemq        | ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /opt/activemq
activemq        | ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /opt/activemq
activemq        | ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /opt/activemq/conf
activemq        | ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /opt/activemq/data
activemq        | Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
activemq        |  INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@6e06451e: startup date [Thu Aug 13 01:34:45 UTC 2020]; root of context hierarchy
activemq        |  INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/opt/activemq/data/kahadb]
activemq        |  INFO | KahaDB is version 6
activemq        |  INFO | PListStore:[/opt/activemq/data/localhost/tmp_storage] started
activemq        |  INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.6 (localhost, ID:ba0d35ec1711-43371-1597282491343-0:1) is starting
activemq        |  INFO | Listening for connections at: tcp://ba0d35ec1711:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
activemq        |  INFO | Connector openwire started
activemq        |  INFO | Listening for connections at: amqp://ba0d35ec1711:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
activemq        |  INFO | Connector amqp started
activemq        |  INFO | Listening for connections at: stomp://ba0d35ec1711:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
activemq        |  INFO | Connector stomp started
activemq        |  INFO | Listening for connections at: mqtt://ba0d35ec1711:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
activemq        |  INFO | Connector mqtt started
activemq        |  WARN | ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@545b995e{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /
activemq        |  INFO | Listening for connections at ws://ba0d35ec1711:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
activemq        |  INFO | Connector ws started
activemq        |  INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.6 (localhost, ID:ba0d35ec1711-43371-1597282491343-0:1) started
activemq        |  INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
activemq        |  WARN | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 3 mb). The data directory: /opt/activemq/data/kahadb only has 49324 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 49324 mb
activemq        |  WARN | Temporary Store limit is 51200 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: /opt/activemq/data only has 49321 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 49321 mb
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13 01:34:55,951 main INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
simplewebapp    |
simplewebapp    |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
simplewebapp    |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
simplewebapp    | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
simplewebapp    |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
simplewebapp    |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
simplewebapp    |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
simplewebapp    |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.1.RELEASE)
simplewebapp    |
activemq        |  INFO | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:34:57.805+0000 INFO Starting AppConfiguration v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on 938a401683ba with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:34:57.897+0000 DEBUG Running with Spring Boot v2.3.1.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.7.RELEASE
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:34:57.906+0000 INFO No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
activemq        |  INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/
activemq        |  INFO | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/api/jolokia/
activemq        |  INFO | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
activemq        |  INFO | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
activemq        |  INFO | jolokia-agent: Using policy access restrictor classpath:/jolokia-access.xml
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:35:04.244+0000 INFO Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:35:04.448+0000 INFO Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 134ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:35:08.972+0000 INFO Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:35:09.004+0000 INFO Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:35:09.006+0000 INFO Starting service [Tomcat]
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:35:09.008+0000 INFO Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:35:09.228+0000 INFO Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:35:09.232+0000 INFO Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 10816 ms
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:35:10.228+0000 INFO employeedb - Starting...
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:35:10.683+0000 INFO employeedb - Start completed.
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:35:11.768+0000 INFO Successfully acquired change log lock
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:35:11.870+0000 WARN Cannot create filesystem for url jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/: null
simplewebapp    | java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: null
simplewebapp    |       at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:171) ~[zipfs.jar:1.8.0_212]
simplewebapp    |       at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:157) ~[zipfs.jar:1.8.0_212]
simplewebapp    |       at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:143) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.loadRootPaths(ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.java:63) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.init(ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.java:47) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.openStreams(ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.java:94) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.resource.AbstractResourceAccessor.openStream(AbstractResourceAccessor.java:17) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:25) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:223) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Liquibase$1.run(Liquibase.java:194) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:159) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:170) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:158) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:137) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:1790) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:183) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:322) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:270) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) [spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) [spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) [spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) [spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) [spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at com.mastery.java.task.config.AppConfiguration.main(AppConfiguration.java:13) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
simplewebapp    |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
simplewebapp    |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
simplewebapp    |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
simplewebapp    |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
simplewebapp    | 2020-08-13T01:35:11.887+0000 WARN Cannot create filesystem for url jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-web-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/: null
simplewebapp    | java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: null
simplewebapp    |       at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:171) ~[zipfs.jar:1.8.0_212]
simplewebapp    |       at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:157) ~[zipfs.jar:1.8.0_212]
simplewebapp    |       at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:143) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.loadRootPaths(ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.java:63) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.init(ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.java:47) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.openStreams(ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.java:94) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.resource.AbstractResourceAccessor.openStream(AbstractResourceAccessor.java:17) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:25) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:223) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Liquibase$1.run(Liquibase.java:194) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:159) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:170) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:158) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:137) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:1790) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:183) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:322) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:270) ~[liquibase-core-4.0.0.jar!/:?]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) [spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) [spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) [spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) [spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) [spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
simplewebapp    |       at com.mastery.java.task.config.AppConfiguration.main(AppConfiguration.java:13) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
simplewebapp    |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
simplewebapp    |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
simplewebapp    |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
simplewebapp    |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
simplewebapp    |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) [app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

Liquibase initializing DB and app works.

Comment: It will be helpful to us if you could add more information to the question such as: The `Dockerfile`, the commands you are running, full logs from the commands run.

Comment: I see from the stack trace you're using Liquibase 4.0.0 and the problem you describe  sounds like the [Extraneous Output from liquibase-maven-plugin:4.0.0](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1339) issue I opened.

I think you had to specify a `liquibase.version` somewhere to pick that up. I'd suggest getting the liquibase.version from Spring Boot since that's a version that has been verified to work.

Comment: There's a bug related to this. See [https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1276](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1276)